# phone gap screen images doesn't fit the screen

Tags: android, cordova

android app with phone gap but the images in the html pages are bigger then the android screen. can u provide me the solution how the icons in the html page will be re sized as per the screen.
Please find the code attached. how to reset  the images to fit to screen.
you can download android source code here
https://rapidshare.com/files/422996060/PhoneGap.zip

Comment: Very few people will download a zip file.  Please provide a SSCCE

Comment: do u want me to paste the source code ?

Comment: Yes, we need to see how you are showing your images.  We only need the HTML, not all the droid stuff.  OR, if your phonegap HTML pages are on the web, a link would be helpful.

Comment: HI,i have placed the app in the GIT hub repository this is link to the html file which has the problem https://github.com/gurulakshman/phonegap-scit-allapps/blob/master/www/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you're specifying an absolute width in your code.  If you want to just leave it up to the browser to determine the width, you could do something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4m5xd/).

```
<img src="someImage.jpg" width="100%">
```

Change the size of the 'result' window and you will see that the images expand and contract to fit the page.

If you need to have exact widths in your phonegap application, you could use [this plugin](https://github.com/raananw/PhoneGap-Image-Resizer) for Android.

Answer (score 0):

you can even do that with:

```
img {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    }
```